# What is the difference between backend_roles vs and_backend_roles in AWS OpenSearch role mapping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

Opensearch role mapping is the process by which users are mapped to internal OpenSearch roles, which grant permissions for those roles to access documents and indices.

When configuring role mapping via [OpenSearch's yaml files](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/configuration/yaml/#roles_mappingyml), the following properties are supported (example from the docs is below):

```
kibana_user:
reserved: false
hidden: false
backend_roles:
- "kibanauser"
hosts: []
users: []
and_backend_roles: []
description: "Maps kibanauser to kibana_user"
```

My understanding of the above is that it says "a user with an externally defined role (e.g. role is coming from LDAP) with the value `kibanauser` needs to be mapped to an OpenSearch role called `kibana_user`".

However, it is not clear to me what `and_backend_roles` means - I can not find it described in the documentation. What does `and_backend_roles` mean in the context of role mapping and how does it differ from `backend_roles`?

Answer (score 0):

The backend_roles is meant for mapping the AWS IAM roleArn to the opensearch role. That way if a AWS resource (lambda or ec2) assumes that roleArn then that resource can have the same permission as Opensearch role has in the domain.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which is asking about `and_backend_roles`.